# Can Silverlight copy a graphic from the clipboard?

Tags: silverlight

Can a Silverlight application copy a graphic/bitmap from the clipboard? If so, how is this done?

Comment: From silverlight to clipboard or from clipboard to silverlight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there is no direct support for Silverlight clipboard.

If you want clipboard access for text, then probably you need to look at [this blog post by Jeff Wilcox](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2008/05/clipboard-access/)

Silverlight manager [though admits](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/427.aspx) that there is no clipboard support

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no way to access image data from the clipboard.  You would need to save the data on a clipboard to a file and then load the image from the file via `OpenFileDialog`.

With Silverlight 4 you make that process ever so slightly slicker by dragging the file onto your silverlight app.

Answer (score 1):

Coming up in Silverlight 4 (hopefully the next beta) there is rumored to be support for image formats on the clipboard.  Silverlight 4 supports text on the clipboard and I'm keeping my fngers crossed that it will extent to images by RTM.